# Install jupyter on RHEL

Tags: redhat, rpm, jupyter

I've been using jupyter on windows until now but I want to install it on my RHEL machine. I can't seem to find anything other than pip which is not an option for me.
Is there an rpm package?

Answer (score 1):

On RHEL systems, one typically runs "yum search jupyter" to find a package.

At least on CentOS7, there is no jupyter package available.

There is a python-jupyter package on Fedora 24 which might be back ported (and might be usefully added to EPEL if you request).